# Is there a way to find out which of my github repositories have github pages enabled?

Tags: github

I don't want to check 200+ repositories manually, and I'm not seeing anything in `gh` documentation how to get it from the API.

Is there any automated way to get this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Is there any automated way to get this information?

Yes:

> You can use the [GitHub API rpeos Pages](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#pages)
>
> > The GitHub Pages API retrieves information about your [GitHub Pages](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages) configuration, and the statuses of your builds.
> > Information about the site and the builds can only be accessed by
> > authenticated owners, even if the websites are public.
> >
> > In GitHub Pages API endpoints with a status key in their response, the value can be one of:
> >
> > - **`null`**: The site has yet to be built.
> > - **`queued`**: The build has been requested but not yet begun.
> > - **`building`**:The build is in progress.
> > - **`built`**: The site has been built.
> > - **`errored`**: Indicates an error occurred during the build.
>
> You can then force a GitHub Page repository to rebuild, through
> [GitHub Action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61706020/6309), if you want.

Source: [Is there any way to filter GitHub repo that is GitHub page enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68696822/3536342), answer by [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc)